# Can't touch / write to filename which does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, debian

On my Debian VM, some of my Stata code analyzing a dataset is failing because it cannot write to the temporary data output file specified in the code. The file, however, does not exist in the directory, and the directory permissions seem to be sufficient. Details:

- The filename is `firm_data_prepared_F10X_allf102s.dta`, so it shouldn't be misread as a directory or anything like that
- `ls` and `ls -a` do not show the file at its name, this holds even when running them with `sudo`
- I cannot `touch` the file with its name, getting the error message "cannot access 'firm_data_prepared_F10X_allf102s.dta': No such file or directory"
- I can `touch` any other filename I've tried in the same directory and `ls` them so it does not seem to be an issue with directory permissions
- The directory in question is mounted from a shared file server
- `fuser` also tells me the file does not exist

How can I investigate this further? Could it be that another user on another machine has created this file in a way that I don't see it by accident?

Comment: ***"...is failing because it cannot write to the temporary data output file specified in the code."*** what exactly is the error, maybe that can help someone find the issue. (Just as an example, perhaps you actually need to create the file first before using it for this output.)

Comment: And to check on your hypothesis about someone having created that file. How about changing the filename temporarily to something random and see if it helps.

Comment: "The directory in question is mounted from a shared file server" Is it mounted read-only or read-write?

Comment: @YisroelTech: As mentioned in my post, I can `touch` any other filename, but can't `touch` the original one — so the error isn't specific to Stata, it also happens trying to work w/ the filename in Bash. Other filenames work, as written (also in Stata).

Comment: This question may get better answers on stackoverflow

Comment: @glennjackman: As indicated by the fact that I can touch any other filename in the directory, it's not readonly. But if it makes a difference, I can also write to other files in the same directory with Stata.

Comment: While I'm sure you know better than that, I'm afraid that there is some kind of typo in the path you're using when trying this firm_data_prepared_F10X_allf102s.dta file, both in Stata and in the terminal. Are you cd'd in to that directory and trying ```touch``` without a directory path, and it still fails with the same error?

Comment: @YisroelTech: Yes, all the bash commands were run directly inside the directory. Stata uses a full path, but it only fails with this exact filename, not if I leave the path untouched and just change the file name.